# Почему не правильно отображается?

Tags: php

Почему если сообщений нет на странице пользователя, то он отображает будто есть, только пустое сообщение с кнопками удаления, а должно выходит просто сообщение о том что сообщений нет.

```
    <?           
      if ($myrow['login'] == $login) {
           $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM    messages WHERE poluchatel='$login' ORDER BY id ASC",$db); /* ORDER BY id DESC*/
          $messages =    mysql_fetch_array($tmp);//извлекаем сообщения    пользователя, сортируем по идентификатору в обратном порядке, т.е. самые    новые сообщения будут вверху
        /*if (!empty($messages['id'])) {*/
        do //выводим    все сообщения в цикле
          {
        $author = $messages['author'];
        $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT avatar,id    FROM users WHERE login='$author'",$db); //извлекаем аватар автора 
        $myrow4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);
   if (!empty($myrow4['avatar']))    {//если такового нет, то выводим стандартный (может    этого пользователя уже давно удалили)
        $avatar = $myrow4['avatar'];
        }
        else {$avatar =    "avatars/net-avatara.jpg";}
 printf("<div id='message_block1'>
             <a href='page.php?id=%s'><div class='message_avatar'><img width='70px' hight='70' alt='аватар'    src='%s'></div></a>             
             <div class='message_author'>  <a href='page.php?id=%s'>%s</a></div><br>
              <div class='message_date'>    %s<br/></div>
               <div class='message_message'>  Сообщение:<br/></div>
                <div class='message_block'>  %s<br/></div>
           <br/>
         <div class='message_drop'> <a href='drop_post.php?id=%s'>Удалить</a></div> 
    </div>                                   ",$myrow4['id'],$avatar,$myrow4['id'],$author,$messages['date'],$messages['text'],$messages['id']);
          //выводим само сообщение 
          }
             while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
                }
                  else    {
                              //если сообщений не найдено
                  echo    "Сообщений нет";
                          }
      /*  }*/
 ?>
```

Comment: Простите, я не могу прочитать вашу индентацию

Comment: @Fike, все же видно.

Comment: @lifting, к какому блоку относится последний `else`? Мне вот не видно ни разу.

Answer (score 1):

Форматируйте лучше и лишние комментарии в коде не к чему, их тоже желательно вырезать перед тем, как выкладывать вопрос. Чем читабельнее, тем больше шансов, что в этом станет кто-то копаться)

В остальном я не вижу, что бы была проверка на то, что у пользователя нет сообщений. Смотрите комментарии(код я сократил до сути):

```
if ($myrow['login'] == $login) {
    do {
       /* Цикл do-while выполнится хотя бы 1 раз точно, даже если $tmp пустой. Смотрите документацию. */ 
    } while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
} else {
    /* Проверка по логину? Мне не кажется, что этот echo должен быть тут. */
    echo    "Сообщений нет";
}
```

Comment: Ой, условие не правильное. А какой условие надо поставить, чтоб было правильно... что то я тут запутался.

Comment: Вот я не знаю как поставить условие на проверку сообщения у пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Я оказывается как то комментировал строки и забыл убрать их, поэтому не работали они, так как не было условие на проверку сообщение по id. Всем спасибо за помошь!